# Fire simulation does not show when I re-open the file

Tags: rendering

I created a fire simulation. It was working and good. But I saved it using "Save as". After I reopened it there was nothing showing.

Render View
[image: Render View]

Here top left kept saying "Updating Mesh" "Updating Images"
I changed my render engine
Changed material

Solid View also corrupted
Doesn't Show fire

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully fixed it
There was problem with cache
Freeing data and re-baking helped